# Events not firing on dynamically created elements (JQuery)

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a page that requires a user to be able to create input elements, and I need to be able to retrieve the data from those elements based on events tied to them.  I am appending them to the body of the document, and they are appending properly, but then their events aren't firing.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/g7Sdm/2/

**Base HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" class="userInput" value="I'm a radio button that already existed when the page loaded." />Pre-Existing Radio Button
<input type="text" class="userInput userTextInput" value="Text" />
<button type="button" id="addRadio">Add Radio Button</button>
<button type="button" id="addText">Add Text Input</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addRadio").click(function() {
           $("html").append("<input type=\"radio\" class=\"userInput\" value=\"I'm a dynamically added radio button!\" />New Radio Button<br />");
    });
    $("#addText").click(function() {
           $("html").append("<input type=\"text\" class=\"userInput userTextInput\" value=\"Text\" /><br />");

    });
    $(".userInput").click(function() {
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
    $(".userTextInput").keyup(function() {
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help!! It is very late and I need sleep, but I'll check back in the morning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `on()` method, as the elements have to be binded dinamically

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addRadio").click(function() {
           $("html").append("<input type=\"radio\" class=\"userInput\" value=\"I'm a dynamically added radio button!\" />New Radio Button<br />");
    });
    $("#addText").click(function() {
           $("html").append("<input type=\"text\" class=\"userInput userTextInput\" value=\"Text\" /><br />");

    });
    $(document).on("click","userInput",function() {
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
    $(document).on("click",".userTextInput",function() {    
        alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/fUBrj/)

Comment: Thank you as well, kind sir.

Comment: no problem, feel free to check the demo I included so you can test this solution

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".userInput", function() {
    alert($(this).val()); 
});

$(document).on("click", ".userTextInput", function() {
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```